# Django annotate data by date for empty result

Tags: python, django, orm, django-annotate

Suppose I have a object model A, and it has a field called created, which is a datetime type field.

If I use annotate to count how many A are created each day, I can use

```
A.objects.annotate(date=Trunc('created', 'day', output_field=DateField()) ).values('date').order_by('date').annotate(count=Count('id'))
```

After that, I can get the result, which looks like

```
[{date: '2018-07-22', count:1 }, {date: '2018-07-23', count:1 }, {date: '2018-07-25', count:1 }]
```

However, notice that I miss a 2018-07-24 because it didn't create any A in that day. Is there any way to let result to have `{date: '2018-07-24', count:0 }` inside that queryset?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? thanks

Comment: Hi, maybe try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52290430/annotation-to-count-and-return-zero-when-there-is-no-relation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django + PostgreSQL: Fill missing dates in a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31682737/django-postgresql-fill-missing-dates-in-a-range)

Comment: @MarekNaskret the answer there is not applicable because that question is for the case when there are related models. (The “when there is no relation” part of the question title is misleading.) This question is in the context of a single model, and the query can only work with the same model's attributes.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52290430/annotation-to-count-and-return-zero-when-there-is-no-relation

Answer (score 0):

My variant for PostgreSQL:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
from django.db.models.functions import Trunc
from django.db.models.expressions import Value
from django.db.models import Count, DateField

# A is model

start_date = date(2022, 5, 1)
end_date = date(2022, 5, 10)

result = A.objects\
    .annotate(date=Trunc('created', 'day', output_field=DateField())) \
    .filter(date__gte=start_date, date__lte=end_date) \
    .values('date')\
    .annotate(count=Count('id'))\
    .union(A.objects.extra(select={
             'date': 'unnest(Array[%s]::date[])' %
                     ','.join(map(lambda d: "'%s'::date" % d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
                                  set(start_date + timedelta(n) for n in range((end_date - start_date).days + 1)) -
                                  set(A.objects.annotate(date=Trunc('created', 'day', output_field=DateField())) \
                                               .values_list('date', flat=True))))})\
            .annotate(count=Value(0))\
            .values('date', 'count'))\
    .order_by('date')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Define your date range

```
start_date = datetime(2018, 7, 22).date()
end_date = datetime(2018, 7, 25).date()
```

Annotate the queryset to count the occurrences of each date

```
annotated_queryset = A.objects.annotate(
    date=TruncDate('created')
).values('date').annotate(
    count=Count('id')
).order_by('date')
```

Generate a list of dates within the date range

```
date_objects = [start_date + timedelta(days=i) for i in range((end_date - start_date).days + 1)]
```

Create a dictionary mapping dates to counts from the annotated queryset

```
count_dict = {entry['date']: entry['count'] for entry in annotated_queryset}
```

Create a list of dictionaries containing all dates within the range, with their respective counts,
filling in missing dates with a count of zero

```
result = [
    {'date': date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), 'count': count_dict.get(date, 0)}
    for date in date_objects
]
```